# What version of SQL Server 2014 Express to install? What are the differences?

Tags: sql-server

I need sql server express 2014 and when I go to the download page Microsoft asks me for:
[image]

what is the difference between:

`SQL Server 2014 Express with Tools 64 Bit`
and
`SQL Server 2014 Management Studio Express 64 Bit`?

I just need a local express database to be installed and also management studio.

Comment: One is an SQL server, the other one is not.

Comment: Both have management studio then? Ok thanks a lot!

Comment: @TonoNam no, that is not what he said! he said one is the database the other is NOT the database. Management Studio is a tool, and not the DB engine. Read the answers provided already.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**SQL Server Express with Tools**
This package contains the core SQL Server database along with the tools to manage SQL Server instances including SQL Server Express, LocalDB, and SQL Azure. If you need Reporting Services or Full text search, use SQL Server Express with Advanced Services.

**SQL Server Management Studio**
This package does not contain the SQL Server database, only the tools to manage SQL Server instances, including LocalDB, SQL Express, SQL Azure, etc. Use this if you already have the SQL Server database and only need the management tools.

**SQL Server Express LocalDB (MSI installer)**
Do you need to embed SQL Server Express into an application? LocalDB is a lightweight version of Express that has all its programmability features yet runs in user mode and has a fast, zero-configuration installation. No management tools are included.

**SQL Server Express with Advanced Services**
Experience the full feature set of SQL Server Express. This package contains the database engine, Express Tools, Reporting Services, Full Text Search, management tools, and all the components of SQL Server Express. This package is a larger size and will take longer to download.

**SQL Server Express**
Do you already have the tools and just need the database server? This is the core Express database server. Use this if you need to accept remote connections or administer remotely and do not need the tools or advanced services.

from:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/Products/sql-server-editions/sql-server-express.aspx

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server Express with Tools

This package contains the core SQL Server database along with the tools to manage SQL Server instances including SQL Server Express, LocalDB, and SQL Azure. If you need Reporting Services or Full text search, use SQL Server Express with Advanced Services.

SQL Server Express

Do you already have the tools and just need the database server? This is the core Express database server. Use this if you need to accept remote connections or administer remotely and do not need the tools or advanced services.

More info at.
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/sql-server-editions/sql-server-express.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This can be a little confusing because Microsoft provides so many options.

You probably want `SQL Server 2014 Express with Tools 64 Bit` to set up your server.

`SQL Server 2014 Management Studio Express 64` does not include the database server, only a tool to help run queries and manage tables. I suggest that you download this package as well.

Further details from the source can be found here:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/sql-server-editions/sql-server-express.aspx